# Are Federal Pacific Stab-Lok panels installed after 1986 considered safer?

Tags: electrical-panel

All info I read about Federal Pacific Stab-Lok panels reference 1982 and older panels. Are the newer panels different and considered to be safer?

Comment: Can you provide us photos of the panel in question?

Comment: And, some information about what they are and why they might not be "safe"?

Comment: The Panel is a K200-2040C Type 1 closure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do home inspections and I always throw up a red flag and recommend replacement of any and all FPE stab-loc panels manufactured prior to 1984. After a federal investigation that ended in a very shallow *"Duh, we don't really know"* kind of conclusion.

FPE panels kinda disappeared for awhile.  I'm not sure if they were bought out or retooled, but the newer panels and breakers do have a legit UL listing.  In my opinion (backed with 40 years experience), if yours is pre-1983, replace it. A new GE, ITE, etc. panel is not that expensive and you can sleep easier knowing you don't have a questionable electrical distribution in your home.

Comment: This article:  https://inspectapedia.com/electric/Circuit-Breaker-Defects-Aronstein-IEEE-2018.pdf hints that the newer versions may not be any better.